# Left align background login screen

Tags: gnome, login, multiple-monitors, 17.10

After having used ubuntu gnome for quite a long time (since its launch), I decided to try out the new ubuntu 17.10.

One thing hurted me: the background of the login screen (how can you make it so awful?).
I therefore decided to change it by editing the file `/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` as follows:

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: url(file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: contain; }
```

Since I have 2 monitors, I need to repeat it. The output is

[image: Image repeated in a wrong way]

I therefore tried by adding

```
  background-position: left -50%;
```

or

```
  background-position: left;
```

but did not succeed. How can I set its position, s.t. it will work with one as well as with two monitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem, I was able to position the background at the top left of the screen using:

```
background-position: 0 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need pixel-perfect gdm3 login background for double monitor setup, try this:

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(file:///usr/share/backgrounds/bg.jpg);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 2048px 1152px; //your screen's resolution
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

(mind you, it was tested on two identical screens)